# Qual é a finalidade do : (dois pontos) no PHP?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Eu tenho essa questão que está me deixando com pulga atras da orelha. Eu não entendo, de jeito nenhum.

O que quer dizer o sinal de **`:`** dois pontos. Alguém sabe me explicar?

Exemplo:

`if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

Comment: vejo que encontrou esses snippets de código no wordpress, não é isso?

Comment: Exatamente! Eu estou estudando o WordPress de A a Z. estou acreditando que assim vou me tornar independente em PHP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Essa é uma sintaxe alternativa para um bloco que é delimitado por chaves `{ }`. Nesse caso a abertura vira os dois pontos `:` e o fechamento é um `end` seguido do nome instrução que inicou pode ser um `endif`, `endforeach` etc. Essa sintaxe se aplica as instruções `if, while, for, foreach, and switch`.

```
$arr = range(1,5);

foreach ($arr as $item){
    echo $item .'<br>';
}
```

O mesmo código com a outra sintaxe.

```
$arr = range(1,5);

foreach ($arr as $item):
    echo $item .'<br>';
endforeach;
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu só conhecia as chaves. Agora está fazendo sentido.

Comment: Eu fiquei na duvida sobre os dois pontos dentro do "IF", também é uma condição, dentro de uma condição?

Comment: @Narsejo tem um exemplo para mostrar?

Answer (score 10):

Complementando a resposta do @rray. Você também irá encontrar o sinal de dois pontos **`:`** como parte do operador ternário **`?:`** usado para condições.

Veja um exemplo:

```
$user = "gato";

echo ($user === "gato") ? "meow" : "nao eh um gato :(";
```

Saída:

> meow

[Veja mais na documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Essa eu sabia. Era exatamente o que estava me confundindo muito. Agora tudo está fazendo sentido pra mim.